# Inserting email in SQLite database using JDBC

Tags: java, sqlite, sqlitejdbc

I am trying to insert an email ID to a table in my SQLite3 Database. In my case it successfully creates the table but gives an error while inserting a record in it - "near "@gmail": syntax error". How can i resolve this ? Here is the code -

```
public void insertData(String emailId, double gtse, long receivedDate) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    Connection connection = null;

    try
    {
      // create a database connection
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:testdb.sqlite");
      Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
      statement.setQueryTimeout(30);  // set timeout to 30 sec.

      ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='T1'");
      if(!result.next()){
          statement.executeUpdate("create table T1 (email TEXT, gtse REAL, receiveddate DATE)");

      statement.executeUpdate("insert into T1 values(" + emailId + ", "+ gtse +", "+ receivedDate +")");      
      }
      else{

      }

    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
      // if the error message is "out of memory", 
      // it probably means no database file is found
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
      try
      {
        if(connection != null)
          connection.close();
      }
      catch(SQLException e)
      {
        // connection close failed.
        System.err.println(e);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your core error is that for the insert query you are not enclosing the values to be inserted, in quotes. Your query, after construction, looks something like this:

```
insert into T1 values(whatever@gmail.com, emailtexthere,  04-07-2013)
```

When it should be something like this:

```
insert into T1 values('whatever@gmail.com', 'emailtexthere',  '04-07-2013')
```

The SQL parser chokes while trying to parse your current query, because the syntax is incorrect. The solution to this problem is ***not*** simply to enclose the values in quotes though, but rather to use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). This is because the way you are constructing your query right now is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Here is an example of using a prepared statement:

```
PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
pStmt.setString(1, emailId);
pStmt.setString(2, gtse);
pStmt.setDate(3, receivedDate);
pStmt.execute();
```

Comment: My current query looks like this because i am inserting variables to the database. insert into T1 values("emailId, gtse, receivedDate"). emailId, gtse and receivedDate are variables passed onto this method

Comment: Using a prepared statement will also insert values into your database, but its safer and less prone to the kind of errors your are encountering.